# Converting Materialize Value to Integer

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js, materialize

I'm trying to convert a materialize value to an integer and save the value in a sequelize database. The code below does not work because req.body cannot be read. How would I go about manipulating req.body to change the sequelize types of the price?

HTML

```
    <div class="input-field col s5" name="price" id="price">
      <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">$</option>
        <option value="2">$$</option>
        <option value="3">$$$</option>
        <option value="4">$$$$</option>
        <option value="5">$$$$$</option>
      </select>
      <label>Pricing:</label>
    </div>
```

JS

```
app.post('/newreview', function(req, res){

  Review.create(req.body({
  stars : parseInt(req.body.stars),
  price : parseInt(req.body.price)
  })).then(function(user){
    res.redirect('/');
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect('/?msg=' + err.message);
  });
});
```

Comment: what is the source of req.body?

Comment: req.body stems from the form field that contains the above html

Comment: did you used form.serialize method?